# problem to read files

Tags: c

How to read a matrix saved using FILE*fp in C?

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    FILE *fp;
    int **mat; //matriz de cartas apartir do arquivo
    int n; //numero de jogadores
    mat=(char**)malloc(3*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        mat[i]=(char*)malloc(3*sizeof(char));
        if(!mat){
            printf("erro de alocacao\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    fp=fopen("arquivo","r"); //this is the file to read
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("erro de abertura de ficheiro\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("%d\n",mat[i][j]); //problem here 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the matrix I want to read:

```
1 2 9
3 6 7
4 9 5
```

Comment: Did you perhaps want to mention the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){ 
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){ 
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&mat[i][j]); 
} 
printf("%d\n",mat[i][j]); //problem here
```

being:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){ 
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){ 
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&mat[i][j]); 
        printf("%d ",mat[i][j]);
    }     
    printf("\n");
}
```

What you posted prints outside the bounds of the array

Comment: even i guess that is the problem. Problem is nt well defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read integers into space allocated for characters - your `malloc()` operations are in terms of `sizeof(char *)` and `sizeof(char)` when you need to be using `int`.  This is going to cause problems.

You should review where your print is in relation to your scan; at the moment, you attempt to print only the last number in each row of data, but you need to think about what the value of `j` is at the point where the print appears.

You should probably also be checking the return status from `scanf()` to ensure that the data is valid.  You should probably also be closing the input file; although the program immediately exits at the moment, 'release resources you acquire' is a good discipline to get into.  The same comment could be applied to the dynamically allocated array, too (release what you allocate).